# Force three column layout JS Jquery only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Page:
https://ntsu.unioncloudsandpit.org/resources

Each row of results in the DOM looks like

```
<div class="uc-document-row">
    <div class="uc-document-block ">
        <div class="uc-doc-bg-ext">
            <a class="uc-doc-bg-ext-wrapper" title="2013 Exec Elections Results" href="/resources/2013-exec-elections-results"></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="uc-document-titles">
            <h2>2013 Exec Elections Results</h2>
            <h3>application-vnd-openxmlformats-officedocument-wordprocessingml-document</h3>
        </div>
        <span class="uc-doc-upload-time">
            17 September 2018
        </span>
        <div class="uc-resource-summary">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="uc-resource-show-download">
            <a title="Details" class="uc-resource-details-link btn-2018" href="/resources/2013-exec-elections-results" style="font-size: 10px;">Details</a>
            <a class="uc-resource-download-link btn-2018" href="https://ntsu.unioncloudsandpit.org/resources/2013-exec-elections-results/download_attachment" style="font-size: 10px;">Download</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

With 4 per row.

For entering a three column layout I can delete the fourth and reorder for example:

```
$('.uc-document-row .uc-document-block:nth-child(4)').remove();
$('.uc-document-block').css('width','21%');
$('.uc-document-block').css('padding','4%');
$('.uc-document-block').css('margin','2');
```

However, how would I actually reorder so the fourth element moves down to the next row and ensure exactly 3 items per row?
I assume this would require detach/prependTo?

I can only interface with the page through JavaScript.

Comment: the use of the 'row wrapper' would make a reordering quite complex. e.g. having 4 elements in 2 rows results in moving element 4 to the next row, having then 3 and 5 elements in 2nd row, forcing you to move down 2 elements to a newly created next row. i'd remove the row wrapper, so that you have just a bunch of div elements and then use css techniques to make a 3 column layout...

Answer (score 0):

check below javascript code:

```
$('.uc-document-list > .uc-document-row').each(function(){
    var currentBlocksCount = $(this).find('.uc-document-block ').length;
    // console.log('currentBlocksCount=', currentBlocksCount);
    var flagNextBlock = false;
    if( $(this).next('div').hasClass('uc-document-row') ) {
        flagNextBlock = true;
    }
    // console.log('flagNextBlock=', flagNextBlock);
    if( !flagNextBlock ) {
        $(this).after('<div class="uc-document-row"></div>');
    }
    var nextBlockObj = $(this).next('div.uc-document-row');
    if( currentBlocksCount > 3 ) {
        $(this).find('.uc-document-block').each(function(key, value){
            if( key > 2 ) {
                var cloneObj = $(this).clone();
                nextBlockObj.append(cloneObj);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!!

Almost perfect. I'm trying to clone the last document block if the row has < 3 so essentially force 3 per row at all times but

var lastBlock =$( ".uc-document-block" ).last();
$('lastBlock').clone().insertAfter($('lastBlock'));

isn't working

Comment: if you are using var lastBlock, then in subsequent statements, you should not use $('lastBlock') instead it should be lastBlock or $(lastBlock). Because, 'lastBlock' will be a string & just lastBlock is an object.

Comment: var lastBlock =$(".uc-document-block").last(); $('lastBlock').clone().insertAfter($('lastBlock')); statements written here, will be just creating an another copy of last element & placing it again at the end. Sort of duplicating element. Does it should work like that?